# Does WSO2 support Azure ComputeResource

Tags: wso2

Is there support for Azure integration to deploy and manage WSO2 products, specificaly Elastic Load Balancer.  I am also curious if  JCloud and Apache Stratos support Azure as an IAAS ?

Thanks
--Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

jclouds Azure support is in the works and scheduled to be released with version 2.0. You can track progress here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-664

Once jclouds starts support Azure, this will indeed add Azure support in Apache Stratos, WSO2 Private PaaS, WSO2 App Factory - since these rely on jclouds for IaaS support.

For other WSO2 products, if you do not need the IaaS support and just want to deploy them on VMs in Azure (without autoprovisioning, autoscaling, etc.) you might be able to do so already. I have not tried using Azure ELB specifically but have configured WSO2 stuff with various different load-balancers (WSO2 ELB, AWS ELB, nginx, etc.) and they worked. So Azure ELB might as well, if not - you can probably run nginx in Azure just fine too.